# How to Change CSS of Custom Template JointJS Element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, templates, jointjs

I've been using JointJS for a while now and I'm trying to create an HTML template for my elements. So I've been using the [tutorial](http://www.jointjs.com/tutorial/html-elements) but it didn't quit do it for me.
The thing I'm trying to accomplish is to adjust the color of the HTML element when an action has been performed, like double clicking the element. I did notice the way that the text is changed in the tutorial, but there is no example of changing any colors.

### Edit

I've tried this to get a starting color on the element:

```
joint.shapes.html = {};
joint.shapes.html.OdinElement = joint.shapes.basic.Rect.extend({
  defaults: joint.util.deepSupplement({
    type: 'html.Element',
    attrs: {
      rect: { stroke: 'none', 'fill-opacity': 0 }
    }
  }, joint.shapes.basic.Rect.prototype.defaults)
});

// Create a custom view for that element that displays an HTML div above it.
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------

joint.shapes.html.OdinElementView = joint.dia.ElementView.extend({

  template: [
    '<div class="html-element">',
    '<button class="delete">x</button>',
    '<label></label>',
    '<span></span>', '<br/>',
    '</div>'
  ].join(''),

  initialize: function() {
    _.bindAll(this, 'updateBox');
    joint.dia.ElementView.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);

    this.$box = $(_.template(this.template)());

    this.$box.find('.delete').on('click', _.bind(this.model.remove, this.model));
    // Update the box position whenever the underlying model changes.
    this.model.on('change', this.updateBox, this);
    // Remove the box when the model gets removed from the graph.
    this.model.on('remove', this.removeBox, this);

    this.updateBox();
  },
  render: function() {
    joint.dia.ElementView.prototype.render.apply(this, arguments);
    this.paper.$el.prepend(this.$box);
    this.updateBox();
    return this;
  },
  updateBox: function() {
    // Set the position and dimension of the box so that it covers the JointJS element.
    var bbox = this.model.getBBox();
    // Example of updating the HTML with a data stored in the cell model.
    this.$box.find('label').text(this.model.get('label'));

    this.$box.css({ width: bbox.width, height: bbox.height, left: bbox.x, top: bbox.y, transform: 'rotate(' + (this.model.get('angle') || 0) + 'deg)', background: this.model.get('color')}); // I've tried to add it like a background
  },
  removeBox: function(evt) {
    this.$box.remove();
  }
});

//add a new element like this
new joint.shapes.html.OdinElement({
    position: { x: 80, y: 80 },
    size: { width: 200, height: 50 },
    label: 'label',
    color: '#ff0000'
  });
```

I've also tried to set it like the text is set in the label, but I've no idea if there is a function for that.

Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Thanks a lot!

Tim

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Show us what you've tried so far, so we don't start to show you options you already tried. Also, show us your code so we can replicate and understand what you're after. Thanks.

Comment: Yes of course, I've added my code to the original post :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself!

Apparently it is not allowed to create a different element in the html variable than the given Element. So I had to change the `joint.shapes.html.OdinElement` to `joint.shapes.html.Element` and the `joint.shapes.html.OdinElementView` to `joint.shapes.html.ElementView`

Now it works all fine :)

Thanks for your help!